# Elixir how to get apps in umbrella app to communicate

Tags: elixir

I have two apps in an umbrella app: cap and ed.

I can successfully call the functions in the first one if I use iex:

```
c:\code\a_umbrella_app\apps\cap>iex -S mix
...
iex(1)>Cap.Handler.get_price()
"128.462"
```

but when I try to call it from my other app it gives an error.

```
c:\code\a_umbrella_app\apps\ed>iex -S mix
...
iex(1)> Ed.Usecap.abc(:price)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :unicode_util.lowercase/1 is undefined (module :unicode_util is not available)
                :unicode_util.lowercase('api.coinmarketcap.com')
         (idna) c:/code/a_umbrella_app/apps/ed/deps/idna/src/idna.erl:57: :idn
a.lowercase_list/1
         (idna) c:/code/a_umbrella_app/apps/ed/deps/idna/src/idna.erl:10: :idn
a.to_ascii/1
      (hackney) c:/code/a_umbrella_app/apps/ed/deps/hackney/src/hackney_url.er
l:96: :hackney_url.normalize/2
      (hackney) c:/code/a_umbrella_app/apps/ed/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:30
6: :hackney.request/5
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:432: HTTPoison.Base.request/9
     (cap) lib/cap/handler.ex:6: Cap.Handler.get_price/0
       (ed) lib/ed/usecap.ex:7: Ed.Usecap.abc/1
```

here's the code from my ed app:

```
defmodule Ed.Usecap do
  require Cap.Handler

  def abc(:price) do
    Cap.Handler.get_price()
  end

end
```

and it's deps, I even added in here the deps that cap needs:

```
  defp deps do
    [{:cap, in_umbrella: true},{:httpoison, "~> 0.11.2"},{:poison, "~> 3.0"}]
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? should I be able to call a function in one app from another app in an umbrella app?

Comment: Are you on Erlang 20? `unicode_util` was added in Erlang 20 which only has an RC1 release yet.

Comment: Can you try deleting and refetching the dependencies? I can't think of any reason why it would work from one umbrella app and not from another in any case. The deps is correct since you can access the module defined in `cap` from `ed`.

Comment: I think I have version 19 actaully. maybe I need to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this fixed it but I made two changes. I added cap to the extra applications.

```
  def application do
    [extra_applications: [:logger,:cap]...
```

and I forgot that I didn't originally make this app in the umbrella, instead I made it outside and moved it in, so it was missing some other code in the mix.exs:

```
 build_path: "../../_build",
 config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
 deps_path: "../../deps",
 lockfile: "../../mix.lock",
```